# How to Redirect one Page url to another Page url

Tags: php, html

I want to redirect one page to another page which is something like below..
`https://www.example.com/foobar.php?emulatemode=2` into `https://www.example.com/foobar.php`

I have tried the below code on .htaccess but no luck.

```
<?php
 
header("Location: https://www.example.com/foobar.php");
 
exit;
?>
```

i am trying using 301 but not redirected.
any one can help on this

Comment: PHP code does not go into `.htaccess` it goes to `.php` file. Also ensure there is no `echo`/`print` or similar output before `header`

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` files are [override configuration files for Apache HTTPD](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html). Their contents should be configuration directives for the HTTP server.

The code you have is PHP source code. It needs to go in a `.php` file.

Since your two URLs share the same path, you need to wrap the two statements if an `if` condition that tests the value of `$_GET['emulatemode']`.